# iOS RSS Parser written with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, rss

Any good RSS Parsing libraries available WITH ARC? I've been able to find a bunch of good ones, but they've all been reliant on memory management. Unfortunately, that will not fit into my current project.

thanks

Comment: Did you know that you can turn of ARC for specific files?

Comment: No thats awesome how do you do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Here is one supporting custom properties https://github.com/Alex04/AMRSSParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Ray Wenderlich's Blog. He has a perfect [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) that will suit your needs.